# How to set image in horizontal center of DIV to fill page width?

Tags: css, image, position, center

I want to create a full-width slider using jQuery and CSS. I have 3 images for it with different widths.
Please look at the code below:

```
<div id="banner">
    <img src="image1.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

How can I put image in horizontal center of container DIV `#banner`?
I assume in most cases, `#banner` will be at most 1400px. But image inside it may be more than this size. Also users may use different resolutions. So I need to move image position dynamically to make it center inside the main div.

**Edition:**
For example imagine that `#banner` has 1400px width. If image inside it be 1500px, I need something that moves image to its left side for 50px. It can show image in its center.

Comment: #banner { text-align: center; }

Comment: @MiheyEgoroff this is not what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peQ2R/11/)

the img will be a relative positoned element so you can use the left:50%; and center it by using a negative margin-left of /2 of the image width using jaquery.

this is the jquery example

```
$("#banners > img").each(function() {
var element = $(this); element.css({'margin-left': -(element.width()/2)});
});
```

This is the css example

```
#banners     { width:500px; background:#CCC; }
#banners img { display:block; position:relative; left:50%; border:1px solid #FFF; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try resizing images to fit the parent div size:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hP7hU/1/)

Here I use 600px width image inside 400px width container as an example.

Comment: This will change aspect ratio and affects on image height too.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you need correctly. One possible solution is centering the image via margin. This will center it no matter how large `#banner` is.

CSS:

```
#banner img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/badAdviceGuy/mg4g7/1/)**